# The tangent space to a particular subset of $\Bbb R^n$ at a particular point

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

> Let A be a real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and define the set M by:
>   $$M = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \, | \, Ax \cdot x = 0\} .$$ What is the tangent space to $M$ at the origin?

I think it should be equal to $M$ itself, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Also, if we assume the the quadratic for $A x \cdot x$ has both positive and negative values, how do we show that $T_0(M)$ is not a vector space (and hence M is not a manifold) - i.e. that there are two tangent vectors in the tangent space whose sum is not in $T_0(M)?$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $M$ is the set of vectors isotropic with respect to the symmetric bilinear form defined by $A$; it is clearly a cone (i.e., is invariant under dilation).

Whether $M$ is a manifold depends on the signature of the bilinear form: For $A = I$, clearly $M = \{0\}$, which is a $0$-manifold. If $n = 2$ and $A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & -1}$, then $M = \{(x, y) : |x| = |y|\}$, which is a union of two transverse lines and hence not a manifold.

More generally, if $A$ is semidefinite with nullity $k$, $M$ is a vector subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ of dimension $k$ (in particular, if $A$ is definite, $M = \{0\}$) and in particular $M$ is a $k$-manifold. If $A$ is indefinite, $M$ has a singularity at $0$ and so is not a manifold.

The tangent space to a manifold (or a variety) at a point is always a vector space.

Comment: I'm confused by 'bilinear form' - I thought that $Ax \bullet x$ was a quadratic form, and so the set would never be a manifold.

Comment: Well, $A$ certainly defines a bilinear form $(x, y) \mapsto A x \cdot y$, and the map $x \mapsto A x \cdot x$ is the associated quadratic form. The set $M$ is certainly a manifold if the form is semidefinite.

Comment: Right, I see. So if it is not semidefinite (i.e. can be positive and negative) it is not a manifold? How would one show this?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct: One can show that if the form is indefinite, then $A$ has a basis of isotropic vectors. In particular, the elements of the basis are all in $T_0 M$, and hence $\dim T_0 M = n$. But since $M$ is indefinite, it is nonzero, and so there is some vector in $\Bbb R^n$ not in $M$. Thus, (the variety) $M$ has a singularity at $0$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still don't see how to define the tangent space though, and how to show that it is equal to M itself.

Comment: Since $M$ need not be a manifold, the tangent space $T_0 M$ is $(\mathfrak m / \mathfrak m^2)^*$, where $\mathfrak m$ is the corresponding maximal ideal. This amounts to taking the span of tangent vectors at $0$ to curves on $M$ through zero. Since there is a basis of vectors isotropic for w.r.t. the bilinear form defined by $A$ (this corrects and garbling in my previous comment), these vectors span $T_0 \Bbb R^n$. (Since no algebraic geometry ideas are mentioned outright in the question, perhaps you are working with another definition of tangent space?)

Comment: To be clear, the tangent space $T_0 M$ is (at least in general) *not* identifiable with $M$: the tangent space is always a vector space, whereas $M$ is generally need not be.